# In app purchases from eventbrite

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I need to create in app purchases, which would allow to buy from Eventbrite. Is this possible? Can anyone give me a suggestions how to start or what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You app can not make in app purchases on behalf of another app.  Play store would be a very large target for scam apps if it allowed this behavior.

If you really require interacting with a third party app for something like purchases it will likely require a partnership with the third party.

Play Store will check the signature of apps attempting to make purchases so since your app won't have the signature of the purchase your attempting to make it will fail.

See: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has a project called `Fabric.io`, and that has a sub project called `Stripe`
Easy to use, easy to implement, you can check it out from :

1. [Main Project](https://get.fabric.io/)
2. [Twitters payment project](https://fabric.io/kits/android/stripe/summary)

Comment: It doesn't look like something I am looking for. I need a way that people could buy products from other apps without leaving our app